# Check if Nokogiri HTML document is usable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I want to check if the URL that the user inputs is in fact a valid page.

I tried:

```
if Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://example.com"))
  #DO REQUIRED TASK
end
```

But that immediately throws an error upon attempting to open the page. I want to return the result of whether it is a document of any kind.

I either get the error:

```
no such file or directory
```

or:

```
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

depending on how I try to make the check.

Comment: What if someone passes a URL to an image, or a multi-GB file? Your code won't handle Nokogiri exploding or inadvertently DOSing your host because it ran out of RAM. You need to handle exceptions and try to sniff the URL to determine what you are going to get back before you ask Nokogiri to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start with something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

begin
  doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Couldn't read \"#{ url }\": #{ e }"
  exit
end

puts (doc.errors.empty?) ? "No problems found" : doc.errors
```

Nokogiri sets the document's `errors` array to the values of any errors that occurred during the parsing process.

This only addresses one part of the issue though. Malicious people like to break things, and this would be very easy to break.  In general, be very careful about anything a user gives you, especially if your site is exposed to the wild internet.

Prior to telling OpenURI to load the file to give to Nokogiri, you should sniff that URL and do some sanity checks using a [HTTP HEAD](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head) request to find out the size and MIME-TYPE of the content being retrieved. Once you know those, you can try loading the file.

Comment: I actually came to this myself moments before you posted. This is the right idea indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it's bad style to 'rescue Exception => e' in Ruby.
[Refer: http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/28/why-you-should-never-rescue-exception-in-ruby/ ]

Secondly, for this case, "rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e" would be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with handling exceptions but something like :

```
begin
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://example.com"))
ensure
  puts "not a document of any kind"
end
do_something_whith(page) if page
```

...should do the trick.

or (after reading your comment) :

```
begin
  page = open("http://example.com")
ensure
  puts "not a document of any kind"
end
Nokogiri::HTML(page) if page
```

Comment: I get the same getaddrinfo: Name or service not known exception at the open point. It's like the program peeks in and gets its head bit off at that point no matter what.

Comment: Same deal. It seems like open-uri is the big issue here.

Comment: I had to give the check mark to the other guy, but thank you for leaning me in the right direction.